# Stylish way of copying fields but skipping nulls

Tags: java, pojo

I'm reading XML into JAXB pojos and want to merge fields to my entity pojos. But I don't want to overwrite the existing values if the value from the XML is null (ie. the value did not exist in the XML). So now I have long sets of code like this:

```
        if (addressDetails.getNAME1() != null) {
            org.setName1(addressDetails.getNAME1());
        }
        if (addressDetails.getNAME2() != null) {
            org.setName2(addressDetails.getNAME2());
        }
        if (addressDetails.getNAME3() != null) {
            org.setName3(addressDetails.getNAME3());
        }
```

This is ugly, noisy and Sonar screams about cyclomatic complexity. How would you go about doing this? Things that come to mind:

- util using reflection (slow and not type safe)
- wrapper classes to entity classes (verbose, boilerplate)

I'm aiming for something readable and without lots of extra code.

Comment: Verbosity can be reduced by providing a utility method like `setIfNotNull`. That would save you some double-getting of the property. I don't know if a class with this specific functionality exists but there may be something in Guava, Apache commons or Spring's BeanUtils. As for iterating over these fields, I'm afraid Reflection will be the only way to go. BeanUtils may help here too. `copyProperties` is similar but it doesn't do the null checking.

Comment: Write your own unmarshalling for overwriting an *existing* object. That would be optimal.

Comment: @JoopEggen could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Reflection should be avoided at all costs unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @vertti Write your own [Unmarshaller](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html), passing the to-be-updated object, generally delegating to true unmarshalling, except for setProperty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Google's Guava code library. It has some utility methods for dealing with nulls.

Comment: Actually you just gave me an idea. Using similar method to Guava's `firstNonNull(T t1, T t2)` I can write `myEntity.setName(firstNonNull(jaxbPojo.getName(), myEntity.getName())`. This is considerably less verbose and much much faster than reflection.

Comment: This way, you're still going to code for all the properties your bean have, right?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a flexible but **slow** solution based on Spring's [BeanUtils class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/3.0.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.java#BeanUtils.copyProperties%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

```
PropertyDescriptor[] descriptors = getPropertyDescriptors(YourSourceClass.class);
List<String> ignoredProperties = new ArrayList<String>();
for(PropertyDescriptor pd : descriptors){
    if(pd.getReadMethod().invoke(yourSourceObject) == null){
        ignoredProperties.add(pg.getBaseName());
    }   
}

BeanUtils.copyProperties(yourSourceObject, yourTargetObject, ignoredProperties.toArray());
```

It does away with writing an explicit null check, getter and setter for every field you may want to set.

If you want to avoid reflection, you can shorten this construct:

```
if (addressDetails.getNAME3() != null) {
        org.setName3(addressDetails.getNAME3());
}
```

using a utility method like Guava's [`Objects.firstNonNull`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Objects.html#firstNonNull)

```
 org.setName3(Objects.firstNonNull(addressDetails.getNAME3(), org.getName3()));
```

This won't help you avoid writing a line per property but it will shorten the code considerably anyway.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using Reflection (ofcourse through BeanUils kind-of library) which can do this work neatly.

Comment: Reflection should avoided where possible